# How to make parsed color lighter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Actually in my RecyclerView Adapter i set the background color by doing

```
 holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(currentItem.getSfondo()));
```

Where the parsed color is given from the DB and till this moment all works perfectly but now i've added a bottom bar to my cardView where i will display a price so i would be able to get the same color from the itemView so Color.parseColor(currentItem.getSfondo()) but make it lighter by adding some alpha or idk so the user will be able to divide the text from the price.

So something like that

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use these methods.

```
lighten(Color.parseColor("#636161"), .5);    //.5 is factor to lighten
```

Just add these methods to your Util class.

```
public static int lighten(int color, double fraction) {
        int red = Color.red(color);
        int green = Color.green(color);
        int blue = Color.blue(color);
        red = lightenColor(red, fraction);
        green = lightenColor(green, fraction);
        blue = lightenColor(blue, fraction);
        int alpha = Color.alpha(color);
        return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
    }

    public static int darken(int color, double fraction) {
        int red = Color.red(color);
        int green = Color.green(color);
        int blue = Color.blue(color);
        red = darkenColor(red, fraction);
        green = darkenColor(green, fraction);
        blue = darkenColor(blue, fraction);
        int alpha = Color.alpha(color);

        return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
    }

    private static int darkenColor(int color, double fraction) {
        return (int)Math.max(color - (color * fraction), 0);
    }

    private static int lightenColor(int color, double fraction) {
        return (int) Math.min(color + (color * fraction), 255);
    }
```

**Update**

You can convert your hex color to int color by **Color** class.

```
Color.parseColor("#636161");
```

and can use these methods

```
lighten(Color.parseColor("#636161"), .5);
```

Comment: Actually the currentItem.getSfondo() is in hexadecimal so every cardView getting different background colors from db like FF00FFFF, how can i anyway make it lighter?